# JavaScript value changes to initial value if changing page in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, laravel-8

I made a countdown time with JavaScript in Laravel 8 the goal is to limit how long someone surfs on my website, but when moving pages the JavaScript refreshes and the numbers start from the beginning again, can someone help me so that the numbers don't change to the beginning when changing pages

My controller:

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $pagination  = 1;
        $datas = Q_Question::where('topic_id', '=', $id)
        ->simplePaginate(1);
        
        $topic = Q_Topic::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        $topic->timer = $request->timer;
        // $topic = Q_Topic::all();
        return view('qanswers.show', compact(
            'datas', 'topic'
        ));
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


$.get("{{ url('show') }}/" + id, {}, function(topic) {
  var waktu = $("#timer").html(topic);
});
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 1 * 1 * waktu * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

This my blade:

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
                            jam : 
                        <div id="clockdiv">
                          <div>
                            <span class="days"></span>
                            <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <span class="hours"></span>
                            <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <span class="minutes"></span>
                            <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <span class="seconds"></span>
                            <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

this is my error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: waktu is not defined
```

can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: save the value with a cookie or session for the user so you can use them every time the user changes page

Comment: thank you very much, i change to my value to cookie, it is working for me